# Java error NoSuchMethodError: PropertiesUtil.addPropertySource

Tags: java, log4j, apache-flink, log4j2

When I submit my jar to Flink for execution, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil.addPropertySource(org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertySource)'
```

I checked other answers and I'm using the same version of Log4j according to my `mvn dependency:tree`:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree | grep log4j                                                                                                                                                 
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.20.0:compile
```

What could be the cause of this error and how do I fix it?

PS: The code works fine when running locally. It only produces the error when submitting to Flink

Comment: The most likely cause is that when running on Flink, a different version of Log4J is being used (at runtime) than what you have compiled it with. You are using version 2.20.0 when compiling but for some reason when you're running it, a different version is used.